# Determining number of character in a string

Tags: java, string

Ok what I'm wanting to do is find out if the length of the word entered is divisible by two or not. If it is I want to take the middle two characters (say it was Game, I'd want 'am') and add it to another word.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Assign33 {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.out.println("Enter 3 words(Has to contain 4 letters)");
       String word1;
        String word2;
        String word3;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
       // Reads a single line word
        // and stores into word variable
        word1 = in.nextLine();
        word2 = in.nextLine();
        word3 = in.nextLine();
          // gets each letter if the word has four letters
               //this is the part I want to change

String sub0 = word1.substring(1,3)+word2.substring(1,3)+word3.substring( 1, 3 );


       // Prints the new word
        System.out.println("Can you pronounce: "+sub0); 

    }
 }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, Please post your question clearly then we will be able to answer it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find out the length of a string use [`.length()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29).
That should help you figure out where the middle of the word is.

Answer (score 0):

1. If your input can have more than one word then filter the first word from the
   line.

   word1 = word1.replaceAll("^\s*(\w+)\s*.*$","$1");

   If your input would have only one word then trim it.

   word1 = word1.trim();
2. Find the length.

   int length1 = word1.length();

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, here is what you can do:

```
String myWord = "Game";
String trimmedWord = myWord.trim();

int lengthOfWord = trimmedWord.length();
boolean lengthIsDivisibleByTwo = lengthOfWord%2 == 0;

String middleSection = "";

if (lengthIsDivisibleByTwo) {
    int middleLetterIndex = lengthOfWord/2;
    middleSection = trimmedWord.substring(middleLetterIndex-1, middleLetterIndex+1);
}
```

Then the "middleSection" variable will hold your "am", or whatever the middle 2 letters are.